# Paul Irish Infinite Scroll loading 2 pages at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have a page on my site that displays sale listings, and users can either scroll down it as it is, or apply filters. If the user chooses not to apply any filters and just scroll down it as is, it works perfectly. When they choose to apply filters, I update the parameters of the infinite scroll instance so that it's loading more of the filtered results. Then, the very first time they scroll, the plugin tries to load 2 pages at once, then it crashes and unbinds itself.

Here's the function I'm using to apply the infinite scroll initially:

```
function initInfiniteScroll( $container, flag ){

//Initialize the plugin
console.log('Initializing infinite scroll');
$container.infinitescroll({
    navSelector  : "#paginationControl",
    nextSelector : "#paginationControl a#next",
    itemSelector : "#json_pen",
    bufferPx : 200,
    animate : false,
    debug : true,
    loading : {
        img : "/includes/gif/loading.gif",
        finishedMsg : "No more stuff.",
        msgText : ""},
    errorCallback : function(){
        $("#loader.grid").fadeOut('normal');
    }
    },
    function( entry_json ){
    /* I'm loading a block of JSON to throw to Backbone instead of 
        grabbing html. */
        console.log( 'Adding more stuff' );

        //Parse the entries
        var entries = JSON.parse( $(entry_json).html() );

        //Throw them to the grid
        Grid.addPage( entries );

    });

//Mark it as having been applied
$container.addClass(flag);
}
```

And here is the code to update Infinite Scroll:

```
//Replace the pagination controls
$("#main #paginationControl").html( $("#listing_pen #paginationControl").html() );
var nextPage = $('#main #paginationControl #next').attr('href');
var basePath = nextPage.slice( 0, nextPage.length - 2 ); //Cut off the last character

//Overwrite path
$("#grid").infinitescroll({ state : { currPage : 1 }, 
                            path : [ basePath+'/', ' #json_pen' ] });
```

After this is called, as soon as the user tries to scroll, the next two pages try to load simultaneously and crash the plugin. I put in a few log statements to try to tell what's going on. Here's the console log:

```
loading /organize/10002/listings/all/10001/1001v/all/all/all 
Updating the page scheme 
initializing masonry 
["math:", 1274, 1635] 
in scroll calling the retrieve function 
defined begin ajax 
setting during ajax to true 
["heading into ajax", Array[2]]
retrieving /organize/10002/listings/all/10001/1001v/all/all/all/2 #json_pen
["Using HTML via .load() method"] 
["heading into ajax", Array[2]]
retrieving /organize/10002/listings/all/10001/1001v/all/all/all/3 #json_pen 
["Using HTML via .load() method"] 
["Error", "end"] 
["Binding", "unbind"]
```

As far as I can tell, it looks like the scroll function in the plugin calls retrieve once, but retrieve calls beginAjax twice twice. Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't caused by the plugin itself. When the `opts.loading.start` function is defined, it shows your loading spinner with a jQuery function call, then attaches a callback function which calls the `beginAjax` function to retrieve the next page of results. I modified this slightly, to:

```
opts.loading.start = opts.loading.start || function() {

            $(opts.navSelector).hide();
            $('#loader').show(opts.loading.speed, function () {
                beginAjax(opts);
            });
        };
```

And it just so happened when I was grabbing the next page of results, I was also grabbing its loader. I didn't know that this was possible, but the `$('#loader')` was matching both the original loader and the one from the retrieved page, so the callback got executed twice, once for each loader. I added a `:first` to the selector and now it's working perfectly.

The way I figured this out was by riddling the retrieve function with console.log statements, then logging the scroll function the same way to find out that both were only being called once. From there it was relatively simple to figure out that it was the beginAjax function being called twice, and a quick look at the jQuery documentation explained why. Hopefully now this answer won't be completely useless to everyone else.